# Gestion de archivos crear/ver un fichero

Tags: java, archivo, java-util-scanner

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de empezar a entender la gestión de ficheros en Java me han pedido en un ejercicio que debo crear un método respetando lo siguiente:

> void crearFichero(String directorio, String fichero): creará un
>   fichero con el nombre fichero1.txt

Yo no termino de pillar el concepto parece ser, he intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String directorio, fichero = "fichero1.txt";

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("introduce la ruta de la carpeta");
        directorio= lector.nextLine();

        crearFichero(directorio,fichero);
        verContenido(directorio);
        verInf(directorio,fichero);
    }

    public static void crearFichero(String directorio, String fichero) {

        File f1=new File(directorio,fichero);
        System.out.println(f1.getName());
        System.out.println(f1.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

Mi idea era que al introducir la ruta por scanner se le asigna al método, de hecho cuando uso getAbsolutePath aparece correctamente, pero el fichero nunca se crea, tengo entendido que si no está creado debería crearlo. No se muy bien que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, tienes que comprobar que el archivo no este creado en esa ruta para crearlo, ademas te hace falta el metodo para crear el archivo, que es `f1.createNewFile();`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
       String directorio, fichero = "fichero1.txt";

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("introduce la ruta de la carpeta");
        directorio= lector.nextLine();

        crearFichero(directorio,fichero);

    }
    public static void crearFichero(String directorio, String fichero) throws IOException {

        File f1=new File(directorio,fichero);
        if (!f1.exists()) {
                f1.createNewFile();
            }
        System.out.println(f1.getName());
        System.out.println(f1.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

Prueba este codigo

Comment: Wau muchas gracias!! no sabia si lo que estaba haciendo mal era el pedir la ruta por scanner ya que no todo el mundo tendra la misma ruta en su ordenador y es ilogico poner una fija.